# Get devexpress gridview selected rows on button click in .net web forms

Tags: asp.net, gridview, devexpress, aspxgridview

I have this devexpress aspxgridview:

```
<dxwgv:ASPxGridView ID="grid" ClientInstanceName="grid" runat="server" 
            KeyFieldName="childUserId">
            <Columns>
                <dx:GridViewCommandColumn ShowSelectCheckbox="True">
                </dx:GridViewCommandColumn>
                <dx:GridViewDataColumn FieldName="childUserName" />
                <dx:GridViewDataColumn FieldName="childFirstName"/>
                <dx:GridViewDataColumn FieldName="childLastName" />               
            </Columns>
            <ClientSideEvents SelectionChanged="grid_SelectionChanged" />
        </dxwgv:ASPxGridView>
```

Then I have normal asp button which has click event. I want to know how I can get the selected rows in the gridview, this is the layout I have

[image]

DevExpress version I use is DevExpress.Web.v14.1

Answer (score -1):

In the server event, you should be able to use the

```
grid.GetSelectedRows()
```

method to get the selected rows.

Comment: There is no GetSelectedRows() function available. @Seano666

Comment: My mistake, I was reading the wrong thing.  This support forum post details how to do it.  https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q303022/aspxgridview-how-to-get-selected-rows-from-code-behind